# Once sharing is turned on here, any site collections that previously had sharing enabled will once again be accessible to guests

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, sharing, external-sharing

We have the following sharing settings, where we allow sharing site with external users, as follow:-

[image]

now today inside a OneDrive one of the users want to use the Request file, and to do so we have to change the sharing settings to the follow:-

[image]

but we got this message:-

```
Once sharing is turned on here, any site collections that previously had sharing enabled will once again be accessible to guests. To prevent this, disable sharing from the Site Collections page before enabling it here.

Do you want to enable external sharing?
```

so i am not sure if the sharing setting apply at the tenant level will override the sharing setting inside each site collection? as this what the message is saying? now i want to allow this to only a single user's OneDrive site and not to all SharePoint sites and all onedrive. any advice, what is the way to control this, so the change requested will not be applied to all sharepoint and onedrvie sites?
Thanks